# jQuery file upload not working with autoupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery file upload plugin to upload my files.

My code is:

```
$('#image').fileupload({
    singleFileUploads : true,
    acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    autoUpload : false,
    maxFileSize : 1000000,
});
```

When I set autoupload to true, its working as expected. But when I set it to false and I want to upload file manually with submit button, it is not working and the image field has no image attached.

I have used the following JavaScript:

```
<script src="/scripts/fileUpload/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/fileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/fileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/fileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/fileUpload/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/fileUpload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
```

Can any one kindly tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

To upload your file when you click on a button:

```
$('input').fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    add: function (e, data) {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("p").html("Requête envoyée");
            data.submit();
        })
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $("p").append("Upload terminé");
    },
});
```

With following HTML :

```
<input type="file" data-url="/echo/json" />
<button>Download</button>
<p></p>
```

Tested on Chrome 31, IE11 and Firefox 25 : http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/MEA58/1/

Comment: i have already tried this, this is working in chrome but not working in firefox.

Comment: @Shahzeb I've add some changes and test. It should work on Firefox.

Comment: @Fractaliste can you please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386928/restrict-filetype-size-single-upload-doesnt-work-in-jquery-file-upload