# How to check .xlsx file extension while uploading

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am uploading an .xlsx file using file uploader in MVC. Before uploading the file I am checking the file extension, whether it is correct or not, with this:

```
 var uploadErrors = [];
 var acceptFileTypes =  /(\.xlsx)$/i;
 alert(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length + ":" + acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type']));
 if (data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length > 0 && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
 uploadErrors.push('Only xlsx|XLSX file allowed');
```

It always shows me the error that only .xlsx file is allowed.

For checking purposes, I have replaced file checking for JPG by the following code:

```
var acceptFileTypes = /\/(jpg|png|JPG|PNG|jpeg|JPEG)$/i;
```

which is working fine with the JPG file.
I've gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386928/restrict-filetype-size-single-upload-doesnt-work-in-jquery-file-upload)
which is also not working for me.
Here is the file which I am checking 
Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

I did not check your code, but to do it very simply, why you don't use the "input" tag with the property "accept"

```
<input type="file" accept="*.xlsx">
```

In this case, when you open the windows to uploading a file, you can't choose file will have not the extension .xlsx